# python pyqt interactive usuage

Tags: python, pyqt4

I would like to use edit the functions defining the slots while my pyqt gui is running so that I can debug the program without having to restart it. An example of what I have is, after importing the py file generated by pyuic

```
##-------------------------##

app=QApplication([])
window = QMainWindow()
window.show()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(window)
##-------------------------##
def helloworld():
     print "hi"

ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(helloworld)
```

Now, after starting this program I can execute commands in the console. What I would like to do is after running the program, redefine the helloworld function using the console

```
def helloworld():
    print "goodbye"
```

However, if I do this, both "hi" and "goodbye" are both printed. I would like only for "goodbye" to be printed.

I am going to use this feature to debug my functions, while the gui is live. I am using spyder IDE with python 2.7.6 and pyqt4

EDIT:

After redefining the function, I reconnect the slot. Thereby, the clicked action results in executing the old function (printing "hi") and the new function (printing "goodbye")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefining the function does not disconnect the original signal and does not destroy the original function. It just creates a new function with the same name, preventing access to the original function by anything which does not already hold a reference to it. As Qt already has a reference, both functions are called (I assume you connect your new function to the button?)

One way to solve this is to explicitly call `ui.pushButton.clicked.disconnect(helloworld)` before redefining the function.

Alternatively, wrap your function in another:

```
def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
    return helloworld(*args, **kwargs)

ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(wrap)
```

Then redefining `helloworld` will have the desired effect.

Comment: ui.pushbutton.disconnect(helloworld) give an error message.
==========
>>> ui.pushButton_cal_perm.disconnect()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QObject.disconnect(QObject, SIGNAL(), QObject, SLOT()): not enough arguments
  QObject.disconnect(QObject, SIGNAL(), callable): not enough arguments
====
 I believe this has something to do with pyuic and the "old" slot signal style.
However, I tried your function wrap solution and it worked great. :)

Comment: @user3353373 oops sorry! I forgot to specify the signal to disconnect from. The answer has been corrected now.